# Prevent uploading file OnFileManagerUpload

Tags: php, modx, modx-revolution

Can I prevent uploading file through MODX file manager with handling OnFileManagerUpload event?

The problem is that I want to force convert images to webp onload, so I don't want to have the original image.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this post https://modx.pro/development/16940, here you can find how process files in detail, also you should include webp-convert library https://github.com/rosell-dk/webp-convert into plugin and convert images to webp on the fly.

Comment: Thank you, that was useful to read, but I still can't find solution. phpThumb creates a .webp file, that's works fine, but I still have my original image. So if I upload 'foo.png' I'll have 'foo.webp' and 'foo.png', but I want to have only 'foo.webp'.